# When job is started, NPEs are thrown from the Spring ancestor class

Tags: spring-batch

Integrating Spring Batch into existing Spring application. Tables created. Three new Jobs created and registered. They can be found via jobOperator and jobLauncher. But when invoked, NPEs come out of the ancestor Spring batch class (AbstractJob).

I have tried invoking the job from jobOperator and jobLauncher. Even looking the job up by name in the jobRepository first. The job starts but then the NPEs show up.

```
@Component("processVlsCasesJob")
@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.NO)
public class ProcessVlsCasesJobImpl 
    extends BatchJobAncestorImpl 
    implements ProcessVlsCasesJob {
...
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Component
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public abstract class BatchJobAncestorImpl 
    extends SimpleJob 
    implements BatchJobAncestor {

    @Autowired // custom DAO
    private BatchAuditDAO batchAuditDAO;
...
public interface BatchJobAncestor extends Job, Serializable {
...
Long jobExecutionId = null;

String parameters = jobParametersExtractor.fromJobParameters(jobParameters);
jobExecutionId = jobOperator.start(result.getJobName(), parameters);
result.setJobExecutionId(jobExecutionId);
```

It is like SpringBatch is creating a new SimpleJob object which isn't configured and trying to run that one:

```
2019-01-10 12:54:51.220 INFO  org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator UserId:|IPAddress:|ThreadId:| - Checking status of job with name=ProcessVlsCases
2019-01-10 12:54:51.225 INFO  org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator UserId:|IPAddress:|ThreadId:| - Attempting to launch job with name=ProcessVlsCases and parameters=param_who=AM20909,param_run_type=test,param_submittal_date=2019-01-10 12:54:45
2019-01-10 12:54:51.259 INFO  org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher UserId:|IPAddress:|ThreadId:| - Job: [ProcessVlsCasesJobImpl: [name=ProcessVlsCases]] launched with the following parameters: [{param_who=AM20909, param_run_type=test, param_submittal_date=2019-01-10 12:54:45}]
2019-01-10 12:54:51.260 ERROR org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob UserId:|IPAddress:|ThreadId:| - Encountered fatal error executing job
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:303) [spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:144) [spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:271) [spring-core-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_172]
2019-01-10 12:54:51.261 ERROR org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob UserId:|IPAddress:|ThreadId:| - Exception encountered in afterStep callback
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:359) [spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:144) [spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:271) [spring-core-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_172]
2019-01-10 12:54:51.261 INFO  org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher UserId:|IPAddress:|ThreadId:| - Job: [ProcessVlsCasesJobImpl: [name=ProcessVlsCases]] failed unexpectedly and fatally with the following parameters: [{param_who=AM20909, param_run_type=test, param_submittal_date=2019-01-10 12:54:45}]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:364) ~[spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:144) [spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:271) [spring-core-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_172]
2019-01-10 12:54:51.272 DEBUG gov.texas.dps.dl.batch.admin.ui.jobexecutionparameter.BatchJobExecutionParameterDtoEditControllerImpl UserId:|IPAddress:|ThreadId:| - preRenderView
2019-01-10 12:54:51.272 DEBUG gov.texas.dps.dl.batch.admin.ui.jobexecutionparameter.BatchJobExecutionParameterDtoEditControllerImpl UserId:|IPAddress:|ThreadId:| - resetForWork
Exception in thread "dlsBatch_2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:364)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:144)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:271)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I do not understand why this is happening. I can step through the registration logic into the constructor of the concrete job class (ProcessVlsCases above), into its ancestor, up to SimpleJob (I don't have the source so I skip it) and then down into the @PostConstruct method of the concrete class.

Comment: Looks like the jobParametersValidator and jobRepository are null (not set) in your job. This means dependency injection is not performed. Can you share how you declare your job bean and make sure all dependencies are correctly injected?

Comment: The BatchJobAncestorImpl constrcutor sets the parametersValidator: `setJobParametersValidator(new BatchJobParametersValidatorAncestorImpl());` and in the concrete Job class the @PostConstruct method does: `setJobRepository(jobRepository);` which isn't null when invoked, so YES, the members are populated.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not clear, but to be sure: when a job is started, the "instance" that is run is the one that is registered in the jobRepository, right? SB isn't going to instantiate a new instance on its own?

Comment: Could the fact that I've set up a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and intend to run batches in separate threads within the same instance of Tomcat that the main Spring MVC app is running in?

Comment: I think I may have found the problem:

`Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(
org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution)] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!`

So I made sure the following annotations were present:

`@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)`

I thought that an interface on a class would result in JDK proxies, not CGLIB ones?

Comment: Even the 1 of 3 jobs that does get a JDK proxy has issues:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:359) [spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]
...
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy226.execute(Unknown Source) [?:?]
 at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:144) [spring-batch-core-4.1.0.RELEASE.jar:4.1.0.RELEASE]`

I also note in the log that the constructor of the job class and all its components are recreated 10+ times!

Comment: `so YES, the members are populated`: a NPE at [AbstractJob.java:364](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/job/AbstractJob.java#L364) mean the job repository is null. You have life cycle and proxying issues in your config. I don't understand the purpose of `@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.NO)` on your job and using `@Transactional` at the job level.

Comment: Ok, I've refactored the code twice now and during report registration, the classes are "constructed" and postconstruct is also called. One would think that would be enough. But NOOOOOOO!. When the job is launched, ANOTHER instance is created FOUR TIMES! WTH is going on with Spring? Its bad enough it creates a 2nd proxy when one isn't looking but to re-create the job/read/writer/processor FOUR TIMES when a job is launched is just insane!

Comment: The ".NO" was an experiment that failed. The `@Transactional` is because the concrete job class extends an abstract class that needs a DAO to create audit records when a job starts/ends (a to our older code). But making either class `@Transactional` results in a proxy being created and the final execute method breaks everything.

Comment: Now I'm getting:Scope 'job' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; - all my job beans are set up `@Scope(value = "job", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)`; they are being registered when the custom bean `BatchModeConfiguration` I wrote which finds the job classes and does a `getBean()` on the job class name. Design: the jobs are to be run in separate async threads triggered by the UI while the app runs on Tomcat. If the job scope doesn't exist until it is running, how do I do this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to follow anymore with all these details. Please try to narrow your question and provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the issue in order to be able to help you.